# Given a band of $m$ opaque squares arranged in a circle, can we find a viewpoint from which we see exactly $m/2-1$ squares?

Tags: geometry, computer-science, 3d, computational-geometry

> Given a band of $m\ge 3$ opaque squares arranged in a circle, can we find a viewpoint (i.e. a point on a sphere centered at the midpoint of the circle with a radius large enough to see the whole band from any viewpoint; the viewing direction is the vector from the viewpoint to the center of the sphere) from which we see exactly $\lfloor m/2\rfloor$ squares? Moreover, can we find a viewpoint from which we see exactly $\lfloor m/2\rfloor-1$ squares?

[image: band] [image: example]

I assume that this is an easy to answer question, but I've got problems in arguing. Clearly, each square contributes $2\pi/m\text{ rad}$ to the angle sum of the circle. I don't know how I need to phrase this, but it's also clear that we can see any square whose normal $n$ takes an angle in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ with $-v$, where $v$ is the viewing direction. So, I guess the answer has something to do with $$\frac{2\pi\text{ rad}}m\stackrel!=\frac{\pi\text{ rad}}k\Leftrightarrow k=\frac m2\tag 1\;.$$

But as I said before, I need help to find a rigorous argumentation.

Comment: If $m=3$, there is no viewpoint where you see exactly $3/2$ squares...

Comment: @Rahul Sorry, it should be $\lfloor m/2\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outward normal vectors point in directions $\frac{2\pi k}{m}$ ($k = 0, \ldots, m-1$), as you observe. Let's assume that the face-centers are at locations 
$$
P_k = (\cos(2\pi k/m), \sin (2 \pi k / m))
$$
as well, i.e., on a unit circle.

Letting $\alpha = \frac{2\pi}{m}$, we have
$$
P_k = (\cos k\alpha, \sin k \alpha) \\
n_k = [\cos k\alpha, \sin k \alpha]
$$
where $n_k$ is the normal to the $k$th face. 
Consider a view from a point far along the ray in direction $\beta = \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\alpha}{2}$, i.e.
$$
Q = (s \cos \beta, s \sin \beta)
$$

Now face $k$ is visible from $Q$ if $ (Q - P_k) \cdot n_k > 0$, which simplifies to 
$$
Q \cdot n_k > P_k \cdot n_k.
$$
Since $P_k$ and $n_k$ are the same (in coordinates) and are points of the unit circle, this condition becomes 
$$
Q \cdot n_k > 1.
$$
And then
$$
Q \cdot n_k  = [s \cos \beta , s \sin \beta] \cdot  [\cos k\alpha, \sin k \alpha]\\
=  s \cos \beta \cos k \alpha + s \sin \beta \sin k \alpha.
$$
Letting $u = k \alpha$ for a moment, this is 
$$
Q\cdot n_k  =   s(\cos \beta \cos u +  \sin \beta \sin u)\\
= s \cos (\beta - u)
$$
As long as $\beta - u$ has positive cosine, we can choose $s$ large enough to make this number $> 1$. Let's look at $\beta - u = \beta - k \alpha$. 
For the cosine to be positive, we need
\begin{align}
-\pi/2 &< \beta - k \alpha < \pi/2 \\
-\pi &< \pi + \alpha - 2k \alpha < \pi \\
-\pi &< \pi + (1-2k)\alpha  < \pi \\
-\pi &< \pi + (1-2k)\frac{2\pi}{m}  < \pi \\
-1 &< 1 + (1-2k)\frac{2}{m}  < 1 \\
-m &< m + 2(1-2k)  < m \\
-2m &< 2(1-2k)  < 0 \\
0 &< 2(2k-1)  < 2m \\
0 &< 2k-1  < m 
\end{align}
which has the $\frac{m}{2} - 1$ solutions $k = 1, 2, \ldots, \lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor$.

Comment: Please note that the centers of the squares don't lie on *the* circle mentioned in the question (see the right figure in the question). That's not a problem, cause each of these centers has the same distance to the center of *the* circle, but I wanted to mention it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have said this: consider the inscribed circle for the polygon you've drawn. Choose units so that the radius of this inscribed circle is 1. Then the remainder of my analysis goes through.

Comment: By the way...for the "can you see exactly $m/2 - 1$ squares part of your question, the answer is "sure": just pick $\beta = \pi/2$ and do the same analysis. It might help to work through the example $n = 4$ by hand to see this (for both cases).

Comment: The outward (unit) normals are exactly $P_k$, not $2\pi k/m$. That's easy to observe, cause $P_0=(1,0)$ and hence its outward unit normal should be $(1,0)$ too. (needless to mention that  $2\pi k/m$ is *not* even a direction)

Comment: I was evidently assuming too much: when I say something points "in the 45-degree direction," I was assuming you'd know that this meant $(\cos \pi/4, \sin \pi/4)$, i.e., that you could convert from an angular description of a direction to a cartesian vector representation. I'm sorry for over-assuming. Fortunately, two lines later I give an explicit formula for $n_k$ to alleviate any confusion.

Comment: Also: when you compute $s$ as I suggest, you can find the *actual* distance you need to go (in more conventional units) by multiplying this value by the radius of the actual incircle of your polygon in those ordinary units (i.e., you convert from units where the incircle radius is 1 to units where the incircle radius is 13 inches, or whatever it may be). If $s$ turns out to be 7.5 "incircle units", you convert to $7.5 \times 13$ inches, in this example.

Comment: Why did you choose $\beta=(\alpha+\pi)/2$ and not $\beta=\alpha/2$?

Comment: Because I saw (geometrically) that this would make the range of acceptable $k$-values form a connected sequence of indices. With your choice, you end up with $k = 1, 2, \ldots, m/4$ and $k = m - m/4, m-m/4 + 1, ..., m$ (more or less), i.e., a wrap-around sequence. I didn't want to introduce modular arithmetic, so I chose carefully. Actually, $\beta = \alpha/2 + \pi$ might have been even cleaner...but I didn't see that right away. Roughly: it meant that expressing $\cos t > 0$ could be done with $-\pi/2 < t < \pi/2$ rather than saying that was true, "$\bmod 2\pi$".

Comment: No offense, but I think that your choice of $v$ is too complicated. Please take note of my answer.

Comment: Ah. My answer solves the slightly more interesting (I think) problem,  "Can you see $\lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor $ sides?". In particular, for the octagon, it's not only possible to see 3 sides (as your answer shows), but if you move a little off the $y$-axis, to see *four* sides. My solution allows this slightly larger number in all even-sides cases, which is why there's the extra $\alpha/2$. Sorry to have misread the question and therefore given a slightly more complex answer.

Comment: You haven't misread the question. I've asked for both, showing that there is a view point from which we see $\lfloor m/2\rfloor$ and showing that there is a view point from which we see $\lfloor m/2\rfloor-1$ squares. Please note that you state that there are $\lfloor m/2\rfloor-1$ solutions for $\beta-k\alpha\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, but you're giving $\lfloor m/2\rfloor$ solutions.

Comment: In my answer, I've assumed parallel projection. I don't see where you take perspective projection into account.

Comment: Yeah...I was being lazy about counting solutions (because you were lazy in asking the question, and left out the "floor", etc.). When $m$ is even, you actually get $m/2$ solutions in that interval. Try it with $m = 4$ to see.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the idea of [John Hughes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/114036/john-hughes), I came up with the following solution: Identifying $\mathbb C\cong\mathbb R^2$, we can assume that the centers of the squares are at the locations $$c_k:=e^{k\alpha\rm i}\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\left\{0,\ldots,m-1\right\}$$ with $\alpha:=2\pi/m$, i.e. the centers of the squares are the $m$th roots of unity lying on the unit circle. The corresponding outward unit normals are $n_k:=c_k\color{blue}{-0}$. Let $v$ be a view point at angle $\beta:=\pi/2$, i.e. $$v:=ce^{\frac\pi2{\rm i}}$$ for some $c>0$ large enough to see the entire band (but since that's not important, we will assume $c=1$). Notice that the viewing direction corresponding to $v$ is $0-v$ (again, that's not important, but nice to know). We can see the $k$th square from $v$ iff $$\sphericalangle(c_k,v)\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)\;,$$ i.e. iff $$0<\cos\sphericalangle(c_k,v)=\langle c_k,v\rangle=\cos(k\alpha)\cos\frac\pi2+\sin(k\alpha)\sin\frac\pi2=\sin(k\alpha)\;,$$ i.e. iff $$k\alpha\in(0,\pi)\Leftrightarrow k\in\left(0,\frac m2\right)\;.$$

[image]

So, there's a viewpoint from which we see exactly $\lfloor\frac m2\rfloor-1$ squares. Replacing $\beta$ by $(\alpha+\pi)/2$, the same argumentation yields that there's a viewpoint from which we see exactly $\lfloor\frac m2\rfloor$ squares (see [John Hughes' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1715566/47771)).

Comment: This answer is incorrect unless you're assuming a parallel rather than a perspective projection. It's not clear that everything visible in a parallel projection also is visible in some perspective projection. (Indeed, for any parallel projection of a reasonably complex world, there's no perspective projection with the same visibility set.) Things work here because the set of faces you're interested in is *finite* (which is hidden in my answer by the observation that "you can make $s$ large enough," which really amounts to saying that the inf of a *finite* set of positive numbers is positive).

Comment: I'm assuming parallel projection and I don't see where you take perspective projection in your answer into account. In any application, we deal with *finite* sets of primitives.

Comment: I use perspective projection in saying that the face containing $P_i$ is visible from $Q$ when $(Q - P_i) \cdot n_i > 0$ rather than when $(Q - O) \cdot n_i > 0$, where $O$ is the origin. Since you asked for a viewpoint on a sphere centered at the origin, I assumed perspective (since otherwise you'd have said "in the infinite sphere centered at the origin"). If there are simplifying assumptions in a problem, it's kind to disclose them when you ask it. :)

Comment: But you agree to me that my solution is correct for parallel projection, right? Maybe the misunderstanding in my definition of a "viewpoint" comes from my misunderstanding of the term "Gaussian sphere"? What is a *Gaussian* sphere? Is it an infinite sphere?

Comment: Sure -- it's right in that case (for the $m/2 - 1$ problem, and,wiht my addition of $\alpha/2$, for the $m/2$ problem). I don't see any mention of "Gaussian spheres" here, so I don't think that can be the point of confusion. Anyhow, you've got an answer in vector form and complex-number form, and both, with tinkering, can handle the perspective and parallel project cases...that should be enough.

Comment: For parallel and $m$ even, you'll see either $m/2$ or $m/2 - 1$, depending on whether you include $\alpha/2$. For $m$ odd, and a generic view direction $v$...you'll see $\frac{m+1}{2}$ from one side (i.e., $v$ or $-v$) and $\frac{m-1}{2}$ from the other. (Draw a pentagon to see this). In general. If your view direction is parallel to one side, then you'll see $\frac{m-1}{2}$ from both directions.

Comment: I've read that, assuming parallel projection, a viewpoint can be modeled by a point on a *Gaussian* sphere. As you've pointed out, a point on a sphere describes a viewpoint for perspective projection, so a *Gaussian* sphere must be some special thing. Since I couldn't find a suitable definition of this notion, I've hoped that you know what a Gaussian sphere is.

Comment: ah...this surely comes from the "Gauss map" of differential geometry, which maps a surface $M$ to the unit sphere by sending a point $P \in M$ to $n(P)$, the unit surface normal at $P$. Since Gauss invented this, it's called the "Gauss map", and the target sphere is sometimes called the Gauss sphere, I suppose.

Comment: If I didn't missed your point, a *Gaussian* sphere is just a sphere. But in that case, I wonder why the authors of [Visibility, Occlusion and the Aspect Graph](http://www.calvin.edu/~hplantin/papers/IJCV.pdf) (last paragraph before Table 1 on page 5) state that we should use viewpoints corresponding to points on a unit sphere, for orthographic projection, and viewpoints corresponding to *any* point, for perspective projection. I don't get why we can/should do that.

Comment: Let me add another point: You're saying that you "use perspective projection in saying that the face containing $P_i$ is visible from $Q$ when $(Q−P_i)\cdot n_i>0$" ... However, is this *really* correct? Regardless whether we use parallel or perspective projection, I've made the assumption that the we look from the viewpoint at the origin of the band (which is $0$ by assumption in your and mine answer). But when you're checking for $(Q−P_i)\cdot n_i>0$, you're assuming that we look at $P_i$.

Comment: So, I'm a little bit confused about whether it's important to distinguish between parallel and perspective projection at all.

Comment: My assumption about visibility (using a point on the viewed plane) is correct for both parallel and perspective; yours is mistaken for perspective. At least, that's what every renderer ever coded in computer graphics says. And I wrote the book. :)  It's important to distinguish between the parallel and perspective cases for $m$ even because of the way, you get $(m/2)-1$ visible faces: for parallel, two faces must be viewed "edge on"; for perspective, they can both both made definitely back-facing (i.e., a "less than" rather than "less-then-or-equal"). The former's computationally impractical.